# Slim 3 render in controller

Tags: php, slim

I used to work with Slim 2 but when I switched to Slim 3 I had problem to render a page in controller :

This is the call of the controller in routes.php

```
$app->get('/test3', '\controller\Hello:index');
```

This is my controller :

```
namespace controller;

class Hello
{
    public function index(){
        $this->app->render('web/pages/hello.phtml');
    }
}
```

For the controller I simply added this to my composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "controller": "web/"
    }
}
```

The folder 'controller' and 'pages' are in the same folder 'web'
I get the following errors :

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: controller\Hello::$app
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function render() on a non-object
```

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

First, you must add a renderer to the dependency container.

```
$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['renderer'] = function ($c) {
    return new Slim\Views\PhpRenderer(__DIR__ . '/../templates/');
};
```

Slim will pass the container instance to the controller constructor. Save it in an instance variable:

```
private $container;

public function __construct($container) {
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

Then you can get the renderer from the container and return a response like this:

```
public function index($request, $response, $args) {
    $this->container->renderer->render($response, 'hello.phtml', $args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you binding the controller actions to the router? Using something like "Hello::index" or array('Hello','index')?

You're going to need [dependency injection](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/di.html) if you want to use the application variable as a property in your controller class.

Comment: $app->get('/test3', '\controller\Hello:index');